# HTML5 input with multiple type attributes

Tags: html

Our form software outputs all  elements with 'type="text"', but I'd rather take advantage of the new types in HTML5, such as 'email', 'number', etc.

I can add these in at the end but I end up with multiple type attributes, eg:

```
<input type="text" name="email" type="email">
```

If there is more than one 'type' attribute present for an element, which is used - the first or last? And is it valid to have more than one? I'd guess not but trying to get round this situation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you cannot, that will be an invalid HTML, you can safely use `type="email"` instead of `type="text"`, because if browser is not HTML5 capable, it will treat any unknown `type attribute value` as `text`

And if you state something like this

```
<input type="text" type="email" />
```

Browser won't respect `type="email"`

Test Case

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<form>
<input type="text" type="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="test" />
</form>
```

Remove `type="text"` attribute and browser will respect `type="email"`

Comment: Unfortunately, type="text" is generated from the forms system so I cannot override/remove it. Oh well, guess I will have to go with it...

Comment: @neilf Yea, if you can't, that stick with `type="text"`