# Is it possible to use multiple type attribute on input element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to use the same input area as type: text or type: URL at the same time;
Is there any way to that

```
<form onSubmit={this.onFormSubmit}>
     <div className='form'>
         <input
             type='text'
             placeholder='Enter search keyword or image URL'
             value={this.state.searchTerm}
             onChange={(e) => {
                 this.setState({
                     searchTerm: e.target.value
                 })
                 console.log(e.target.type)
             }} />
         <button type='submit'>Display</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

The input area is for image search. And I want the user to either use a keyword or image url. I'm using  unsplash API for image search

Comment: Does this answer your question? [HTML5 input with multiple type attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16231262/html5-input-with-multiple-type-attributes)

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to do multiple types, but you have the ability to swap the type. Basic idea below

```js
document.getElementById("testNum").addEventListener("input", function () {
  this.type = this.value.match(/^[\d.]+$/) ? 'number' : 'text'
})

document.getElementById("testLink").addEventListener("input", function () {
  this.type = this.value.match(/^http/i) ? 'url' : 'text'
})
```

```css
input[type="text"] {
  border-color: green;
}
input[type="number"] {
  border-color: yellow;
}
input[type="url"] {
  border-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<input id="testNum" type="text" />

<input id="testLink" type="text" />
```